# "OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found" Integration testing with ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, razor, mvvm, nunit

I have an issue regarding integration testing within a razor application combined with MVVM. All my classes use ApplicationDbContext.

The Test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ApiParserControllerTests
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public ApiParserControllerTests(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    [Test]
    public void IsOptionValid_Teacher_ShouldReturnTrue()
    {
        var model = new ApiParserController(_dbContext);
        var assign = model.IsOptionValid("Teacher");

        Assert.AreEqual(true, assign.Value);
    }
```

The method class:

```
public class ApiParserController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public ApiParserController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult IsOptionValid(string Option)
    {
        return Json(_dbContext.Import.Any(x => x.Option.ToLower() == Option.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

Running this gives me the error in the title. I have tried adding an empty constructor to solve this problem, however this just makes the ApplicationDbContext null.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I have added a unit test for this method that mocks the database using the inMemory:

```
    [Test]
    public void IsOptionValid_Teacher_ShouldReturnTrue()
    {
        //Arrange
        var optionsbuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsbuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TeacherDB");
        var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsbuilder.Options);

        JsonResult json = new JsonResult(true);
        _dbContext.ImportOption.Add(new ImportOption { Id = 1, isUnique = 1, Option = "Teacher" });
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        //Act
        var model = new ApiParserController(_dbContext);
        var assign = model.IsOptionValid("Teacher");
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(true, assign.Value);
    }
```

Comment: `I have tried adding an empty constructor to solve this problem, however this just makes the ApplicationDbContext null.` Your test needs to `new` up the `ApplicationDbContext ` or mock it somehow.

Comment: @mjwills From what I understood, if I mock the context it would be a unit test, but if I use the current dbContext and made a connection with our database it would be an integration test.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point in a certain way - that's why I'd like to mock data in my unit tests. However, I'd also like to create an integration test. But in order to accomplish that, I would need an instance of ApplicationDbContext. I am not sure how to achieve this. Thank you very much for looking into this by the way!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Answer (score 2):

Remove default constructor in your ApiParserControllerTests, use [SetUp] function instead.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ApiParserControllerTests
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp(){
        // initialize here
       _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [Test]
    public void IsOptionValid_Teacher_ShouldReturnTrue()
    {
        var model = new ApiParserController(_dbContext);
        var assign = model.IsOptionValid("Teacher");

        Assert.AreEqual(true, assign.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some code and links to documentation. Code somtimes tells more than thousand words, but only with some helpful phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a fixture with a constructor that takes an `ApplicationDbContext`. That means you need to supply NUnit with such an object so that it can call the constructor.

OTOH, by using `TestFixture` without any arguments, you are telling NUnit to use a default constructor. That's the source of the original error message, since the class had no default constructor.

Adding a default constructor makes it possible for NUnit to construct your fixture class, but that still doesn't give you the dbContext you need in order to run the test.

Normally, you would supply an argument to the fixture constructor by passing it as an argument to the `TestFixtureAttribute`. This may be difficult to do in your case and it may be simpler to either construct the context in OneTimeSetUp for the class or to mock the context. Which you do depends on exactly what you are trying to test, which isn't clear from the question.

In one of your comments, you mention wanting to use the "current dbContext". This might be the key, if you can explain it further. What do you mean by "current" here? Where is that context created? Then we can figure out how your test can get access to it.